# Getting SIM ID or any Unique Number Using J2ME

Tags: java-me, imei

I am writing an application that run only that user's phone. If the phone is stolen, application will never work anytime. For this scenario, I must used IMEI and SIM number but I develop application on SDK 60 2nd edition. So getting these numbers is not easy.

I used Bluetooth ID instead of IMEI, but I could not found any specific ID instead of SIM number. If any suggestion have been, I' d be glad. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples on how to accomplish this with the IMEI in different phone manufacturers:

http://mobilepit.com/10/how-to-get-imei-number-in-j2me-javame.html

Seems like there's no "universal" method for any of those. In S60 (I guess this is what you mean by 'SDK 60') the appropiate code is:

```
System.getProperty("phone.imei");
```

For IMSI I think you have to get the operators signing, but you could use:

```
System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.imsi");
```

Comment: That is true for the 3rd ed but I develop for 2nd ed, and this properties does not work on it.